# SerializationException: serializationStream supports seeking, but its length is 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I'm using the following Class to save and load User's data on/from persistentDataPath in the Android build of our Unity game. 
This class works perfectly on our tests from the game, but in our Analytics tools, I see some of our users (about 5K from 50K) has the issue that their data has been reset when coming to the game after a while and they are getting the mentioned error in Load() function.

```
public class GameData : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Data _playerData;

    public static Data GetPlayerDataInstance()
    {
        Load();
        return _playerData;
    }
    public static void Save(Data data)
    {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");

        _playerData = data;

        try
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(file, data);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            file.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void Drop()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {
            print("Drop GameData");
            File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");

            _playerData = null;

        }
        else
        {
            _playerData = null;
        }
    }

    public static void Load()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);

            Data data = null;

            try
            {
                data = (Data) binaryFormatter.Deserialize(file);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);                
                 throw;             
            }
            finally
            {                
                file.Close();
            }

            _playerData = data;
        }
        else
        {
            _playerData = null;
        }
    }
}
```

As I read topics about this error, the problem is almost that the saved file (i.e playerInfo.dat) is empty. 
How could it happen only for some users? Is there a solution to prevent this issue?

UPDATE :
This is how Data class implementation looks :

```
[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public bool PlayMusic { get; set; }
    public bool PlaySoundEffect { get; set; }
    public bool PlayVibration { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool SkippedTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool MainSceneTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedHitOpponentMohrehTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedHitByOpponentTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedEndGameExactPlaceTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedEndGameGreaterPlaceTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedEndGameLessPlaceTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedUndoButtonTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedDoubleButtonTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool FinishedDragTutorial { get; set; }
    public bool IncomingMohrehBlockedByOpponent { get; set; }
    public int ClientStickerId { get; set; }
    public int PlayCount;
    public bool FinishedTurnTimerTutorial { get; set; }

    public bool ChangedNameForEnterLeaderboard { get; set; }
    public bool LeaderboardUnlocked { get; set; }

    public PurchaseToken LastPurchaseToken { get; set; }
    public PurchaseToken LastSpinnerPurchaseToken { get; set; }

    public Data(string playerId, string accessToken)
    {
        PlayerId = playerId;
        AccessToken = accessToken;
        PlayMusic = true;
        PlaySoundEffect = true;
        PlayVibration = true;
        FinishedTutorial = false;
        SkippedTutorial = false;
        MainSceneTutorial = false;
        ClientStickerId = 0;
        LastPurchaseToken = null;
        FinishedHitOpponentMohrehTutorial = false;
        FinishedHitByOpponentTutorial = false;
        FinishedEndGameExactPlaceTutorial = false;
        FinishedEndGameGreaterPlaceTutorial = false;
        FinishedEndGameLessPlaceTutorial = false;
        IncomingMohrehBlockedByOpponent = false;
        FinishedUndoButtonTutorial = false;
        FinishedDoubleButtonTutorial = false;
        FinishedDragTutorial = false;

        ChangedNameForEnterLeaderboard = false;
        LeaderboardUnlocked = false;

        PlayCount = 1;
        FinishedTurnTimerTutorial = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the implementation of `Data`?

Comment: @derHugo I also Added Data class implementation in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use properties! ... only **fields** are serializable!

after

```
binaryFormatter.Serialize(file, data);
```

you will always get an empty file.

---

Change your class to use fields instead

```
[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public string PlayerId;
    public string AccessToken;

    public bool PlayMusic;
    public bool PlaySoundEffect;
    public bool PlayVibration;
    public bool FinishedTutorial;
    public bool SkippedTutorial;
    public bool MainSceneTutorial;
    public bool FinishedHitOpponentMohrehTutorial;
    public bool FinishedHitByOpponentTutorial;
    public bool FinishedEndGameExactPlaceTutorial;
    public bool FinishedEndGameGreaterPlaceTutoria;
    public bool FinishedEndGameLessPlaceTutorial;
    public bool FinishedUndoButtonTutorial;
    public bool FinishedDoubleButtonTutorial;
    public bool FinishedDragTutorial;
    public bool IncomingMohrehBlockedByOpponent;
    public int ClientStickerId;
    public int PlayCount;
    public bool FinishedTurnTimerTutorial;

    public bool ChangedNameForEnterLeaderboard;
    public bool LeaderboardUnlocked;

    public PurchaseToken LastPurchaseToken;
    public PurchaseToken LastSpinnerPurchaseToken;

    ...
}
```

where `PurchaseToken` should also be a `Serializable` type.

Comment: what do you mean? you use it the same way as before but now have serialized fields so the file will not be empty.

Comment: Look, when I use my code (with properties) and run it, It works good. Empty situation only occurs for a few users of the game.

Comment: well I don't know for which users your code should work ... the file will always be empty ... but hey .. take it or leave it ;) In general I would actually suggest to rather use a proper format like XML or JSON do serialize and deserialize your stuff

Comment: In unity you can use SerializedObject to save all of this, you just have to put [System.Serializable] on top of the classes and structs that you use and arrays, Lists and dictionaries are supported, so you just assign a variable and its saved automatically by unity (just like any other field in the inspector is persistent, same serialization happens).

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan I guess you are speaking about [SerializedObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html) ... this is used in editor scripts and has very little to nothing to do with saving and loading it fromt/to a file.

Comment: @derHugo yes you are right. I thought that since it saves the data you want in asset files that it could be even used as a database, but seems like all the ways of saving changes to a scriptableObject is by editor tools (SetDirty, SaveAsset, etc).